# Graphic card driver issues Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, graphics, graphic-card, proprietary-drivers

I have a Thinkpad T400 with a ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3470. It appears that the basic installation of my Ubuntu does not "fully use" the ATI graphics card. From what I have read, the fglrx driver does support my graphics card but only on the last LTS (Ubuntu 12.04).

Can anyone give me instructions on how to install a graphics card driver, such that I can get the maximum performance out of my laptop?

Comment: "It appears that the basic installation of my Ubuntu does not "fully use" the ATI graphics card" what makes you think that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proprietary `fglrx` driver no longer supports your HD 3470, but the free software `radeon` driver supports it very well. You should be able to run any 3D software your card is physically capable of running with the `radeon` driver.

To use the `radeon` driver, make sure all `fglrx` packages are uninstalled, and install `xserver-xorg-video-radeon` and `libgl1-mesa-glx`.